# Loading JQuery from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to load JQuery library from a JavaScript file and calling a function that is using JQuery.

> JS1.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //var id = 728;
    (function () {
        var jq = document.createElement('script'); jq.type = 'text/javascript';
        jq.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(jq);
    })();
    ShowData('test');
});
```

Markup:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="JS/js1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="embedloc">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

But its not working. The function is still unable to find the JQuery. When I am adding it manually on the HTML page, it runs successfully. Please help.

Comment: You need to load the Jquery Library before you can use it. Put a script tag to the Jquery version you are using or to the CDN that you are getting Jquery from. Make sure that it is placed before your script that way when your script executes it will have knowledge of the $ sign.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use jQuery before you load it.
That's not going to work.

If you want to load a script dynamically, you can only use it after the `<script>` tag has asynchronously finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

A solution:

```
<head>
   <script>
        document.write('<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">  </' + 'script>');
   </script>
</head>
```

(Sencha Touch framework uses this technique to load scripts).

Hope this helps. Cheers